# How to Autofire up a Sql Statement when a condition is fulfilled?

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers

I have a table `Training` having column `T_StartDate` and `T_EndDate` and so on. Now i want if saved `T_EndDate` matches with Today's Date , I want record of that column should be deleted by itself. for this i have write some code in procedure but i think this would not work as expectation as procedure can not fire up automatically.
So for this issue i read from internet that i need a trigger to do such functioning. But do not have much of idea about trigger.
So please tell me how could i do this?
Also i am attaching a picture for my table so that you guys understand the structure.
Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Why do you actually want to delete the record?  Why not just have a "NoLongerValid" flag or something similar?

Comment: Yes!! This would be fine if i update my table and set flag to false. But not have the idea to do so or query ied up automatically. #Gordan Linoff

Answer (score 0):

Just add a computed column:

```
alter table Training add IsValid as (case when t_enddate < cast(getdate() as date) then 1 else 0 end)
```

You can then access the table using this column or using a view:

```
create view v_Training as
     select t.*
     from Training
     where IsValid = 1;
```

You can then delete the rows at your leisure -- once per month, once per week.

Otherwise, you need to set up a job to run at *exactly* midnight.  If not, there will be a period of time when the data will not be valid.  And, if you miss the update for some reason, you could have problems.